# iOS Exception Backtrace - App entry not symbolicating

Tags: ios, exception, crash, sigabrt, backtrace

I have received the below exception backtrace from Apple for an app I had submitted to the app store. I have symbolicated the log but my app's entry has not symbolicated. Any idea what I can do to achieve that? Please see Entry # 14 below which provides more detail. Any help would be much appreciated

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
 0  CoreFoundation               0x1810cadb0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
 1  libobjc.A.dylib              0x18072ff80 objc_exception_throw + 56
 2  UIKit                        0x186b6d268 -[UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin] + 2884
 3  UIKit                        0x186581fb0 __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke + 1640
 4  UIKit                        0x1865800c8 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 332
 5  UIKit                        0x1864d30c8 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
 6  UIKit                        0x1864e0a80 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 92
 7  UIKit                        0x1862125a4 _afterCACommitHandler + 96
 8  CoreFoundation               0x181080728 _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
 9  CoreFoundation               0x18107e4cc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
10  CoreFoundation               0x18107e8fc __CFRunLoopRun + 928
11  CoreFoundation               0x180fa8c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
12  GraphicsServices             0x182890088 GSEventRunModal + 180
13  UIKit                        0x18628a088 UIApplicationMain + 204
14  MyApp                        0x1000fb144 0x1000e4000 + 94532
15  libdyld.dylib                0x180b468b8 start + 4
```

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for the edit!

Comment: Finally managed to Symbolicate the Crash log in full thanks to a tutorial that explained the process [link](https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/symbolicating-your-ios-crash-reports/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. I was invoking UIAlertController in my code to present an action sheet with various options. To cater to devices that don't have a camera, I had added a conditional statement to directly present an ImagePicker instead of an action sheet.

iPAD testing was carried out only on the simulator which doesn't have a camera, thus directly invoking the ImagePicker. When he Conditional statement was removed, it tried presenting the Action Sheet through a PopoverPresentationController and crashed - as is evident in statement 2 of the Exception Backtrace.

I subsequently added the following code to fix the oversight:

```
 if let popOver = optionMenu.popoverPresentationController {
            popOver.sourceRect = sender.bounds
            popOver.sourceView = sender
        }
```